# Не могу разобраться с XMLHttpRequest метод POST и CORS

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest, cors

Начал знакомиться с XMLHttpRequest/CORS но пока не могу во всем разобраться. Отправляю с локальной хтмл-страницы Аякс-запрос на РНР-файл обработчика на онлайн сервере.

Нашёл простой пример запроса:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', 'http://mydomain.com/myphphandler.php', true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.send('somekey1=somevalue1&somekey2=somevalue2');
</script>
```

РНР-обработчик:

```
<?php
$somevalue1 = $_REQUEST['somekey1'];
$somevalue2 = $_REQUEST['somekey2'];

try {
    // my PDO query
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql.'<br>'.$e->getMessage();
}
$db = null;
?>
```

Все работает но возникает ряд вопросов:

**1.** Правильно ли отправляю данные т.е.

`request.send('somekey1=somevalue1&somekey2=somevalue2');`

или это при GET-запросе а при **POST** как то иначе отправлять нужно?

**2.** Дает ли возможность XMLHttpRequest отправлять кроссдоменные запросы без прописания заголовка **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** на обработчике? И если да и мой запрос является CORS-запросом то почему получаю все равно ошибку

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mydomain.com/myphphandler.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Или CORS-заголовок на обработчике в любом случае прописать нужно?

**3.** Как правильно прописать ответ в РНР-файле обработчика и получать его на странице, с которой отправляю запрос? Если в обработчике добавляю:

```
echo 'OK';
```

а в код запроса:

```
console.log(request.responseText);
```

то никакого ответа не получаю. Насколько понимаю не получаю status 200

Comment: Надо чтоб сервер куда вы посылаете запрос отдал заголовок типа `access-control-allow-origin:*`. Где может быть как звездочка, так и имя домена, с которого будет ожидаться запрос. Просто `echo 'OK';` в php не прокатит

Comment: Т.е. получается заголовок на обработчике в любом случае прописать нужно если обработчик на другом домене и сам по себе XMLHttpRequest от этой необходимости не избавляет? Т.е. XMLHttpRequest это лишь альтернатива $.ajax только на чистом JS ?

Comment: На сколько я пробовал, хоть и указание заголовков `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` является простым и должен избавлять от предзапроса браузером, как пишут в книгах)), но сколько не пытался все равно приходится ждать разрешения от сервера. с другого домена....и как раз таки `$.ajax` является альтернативой от `XMLHttpRequest `, а не наоборот, так как `$.ajax` - это большая сладкая обертка над `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: Понял, но ответ от сервера все же не могу получить, даже когда прописал заголовок `access-control-allow-origin:*` (хотя теперь успешно получаю статус 200). Вы имели в виду что `echo 'OK';` не прокатит если заголовок не указать или вообще не прокатит и как то по-другому ответ в обработчике нужно указать?

Comment: То есть сервер, куда вы шлете запрос, теперь отвечает с заголовком `access-control-allow-origin:*` ? Я имел в виду, что `echo 'OK';`  не достаточно для разрешения кроссдоменных запросов, конечно же)) без разрешение сервера

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итак. Если у вас и домен, с которого вы посылаете запрос и домен, где обрабатываете запрос под вашим контролем. То есть сервер тоже, то.

Запрос `xhr` выглядит следующим образом, к примеру.

```
var XHR = ("onload" in new XMLHttpRequest()) ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;
    var xhr = new XHR();

    var params = "somekey1=somevalue1&somekey2=somevalue2";

    xhr.open('GET', 'http://mydomain2.ru/?' + params, true);

    xhr.onload = function(data) {
        console.log('good');
        console.log( JSON.parse(this.responseText) );
    }

    xhr.onerror = function(data) {
      console.log( 'error' + this.status ); console.log(data);
    }


    xhr.send('fname=Henry&lname=Ford');
```

Тут я ожидаю `json`

**Обращаю внимание**!
Если запрос `GET` то параметры надо передавать в `xhr.open` вместе с `url`.

Если запрос `POST`, то параметры располагаются в `xhr.send`

Для приема на сервере либо в `php` файле разрешить, к примеру:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
echo json_encode(['test1' => $_REQUEST['somekey1'], 'test2' => $_REQUEST['somekey2']]);
exit();
```

либо `.htacess` должен содержать строки

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type, cache-control, if-modified-since"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "HEAD, GET, POST, OPTIONS"
```

Лучше выбрать то, что действительно вам подходит.. Например вместо `"*"` лучше конкретный домен указать.

То, что я сейчас написал - все работает.

Comment: json в обработчике вы указали **НЕ** в json-формате, должно быть: `echo json_encode('{"test1":"$_REQUEST[\'somekey1\']", "test2":"$_REQUEST[\'somekey2\']}');`, теперь работает

Comment: @stckvrw я указал массив, который с помощью `json_encode` преобразуется в `json` ;-)   Просто квадратные скобки массива - синтаксис `php 5.4`,  ;-)  для версий ниже надо : `echo json_encode(array('test1' => $_REQUEST['somekey1'], 'test2' => $_REQUEST['somekey2']));` Так что все правильно я написал.... , это вам на будущее, чтоб не извращаться с обратными слэшами)