# Как обратиться к другому сайту яваскриптом и получить json

Tags: javascript

Добрый день,
хочу сделать информер для сайта , но столкнулся с проблемой что нет нормальных решений , подскажите как можно javascript (чистым без библиотек) по ссылке обратиться к другому сайту и забрать json соответственно на моем сайте получить данные из json  ?

или может кто-то может поделиться рабочими решениями для создания информера

Comment: забыл уточнить , ссылка на php файл который отдает json

Comment: кросс-доменные запросы вообще-то запрещены

Comment: так я же хочу к своему сайту и буду другим сайтам отдавать информацию для информера

Comment: О, оказывается я ответ писал даже [XMLHttpRequest метод POST и CORS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/462595/191482)

Comment: супер , спасибо то что нужно

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу разобраться с XMLHttpRequest метод POST и CORS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/462571/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81-xmlhttprequest-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-post-%d0%b8-cors)